# BitBucket get account owner for given folder with Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there any command in Git to know who the BitBucket account owner is for a local folder that use Git?, I have always had to do `add`, `commit` and `push` to know the BitBucket account owner. (I can find the owner in the URL when I'm prompted for a password during `git push`.)

I would like to know if there is a simple way to do it without pushing whatever changed.

Comment: Who owns the file? Check with `ls -la`?

Comment: The owner of a folder is an OS, not a Git, thing.

Comment: i am not being very clear, i mean to the account owner but in bitbucket, i'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that BitBucket owners are based on the repo, not on folder.)

The URL you see during the `git push` command is attached to the Git remote, and is how Git determines where to push your commits.

To see this URL without pushing, do:

```
git remote -v
```

That should give you some output like this:

```
origin   git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>.git
```

Where `<username>` is the name of the account owner, and `<repository>` is the name of the repository.